# Symfony 2 'Any' element of collection constraint

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

Is there a built-in symfony 2 way, to make sure that at least one element in array is equal to X? I already had to create custom constraint to make sure that no two elements are equal. Collection contstraint isn't an option, as it requires named items, and mine are all anonymous and equal to each other.

So in essence: something like All, but returning true when at least one element matches all requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. However, there is a request about implementing such thing: [Improve support for collection validation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9888)

Comment: Didn't know there was ongoing RFC, and I was going to propose one. Looks like three weeks ago it was merged into 2.5 dev branch